# os.path.exists() returning False for one and True for another file. Both files exist

Tags: windows, python-2.7, os.path

So I'm trying to convert some files with script I have that includes wave and os module.

For some reason, the script wouldn't work when entering absolute path of a file, so I decided to do a little testing and wrote this code:

```
import os
print os.path.exists("C:\Users\mavri\Desktop\Bubnjevi\Bass-Drum-1.wav")
print os.path.exists("C:\Users\mavri\Desktop\proba\testni.wav")
```

As you can see on screenshots I provided below, both files exist, I rechecked path a couple of times just to be sure, but I get True for the first statement and False for the second one.

Screenshot 1: (proof that the first file exists) http://prntscr.com/ekns86

Screenshot 2: (proof that the second file exists) http://prntscr.com/eknr2n

Sidenote: It returns True for Bass-Drum-1.wav file, while it returns False for testni.wav

Comment: Okay, so for some reason, after renaming the file to something else other than **testni**, it returns True, after renaming it back to **testni**, it returns False again. This must be some kind of a bug I guess.

Comment: `"\t"` is a tab character, which isn't allowed in a Windows filename. I suggest using forward slashes for path literals to avoid having to escape backslashes. To make sure they'll work consistently in all cases, I also suggest that you normalize them, e.g. `filepath = os.path.normpath('C:/Users/mavri/Desktop/proba/testni.wav')`.

Comment: I will try that, thank you very much!

Okay, maybe I understood you wrong, but I tried the following:

'print os.path.exists(os.path.normpath("C:/Users/mavri/Desktop/proba/testni.wav"))'
and it still returns False.

Comment: My bad, I renamed the file afterwards, sorry!

When we're at it, since it will be a part of a larger application and the abs path will be provided by tkinter's askopenfile, can I simply replace all backslashes by normal slashes without worrying it will introduce more bugs?

Comment: Did you mean `askopenfilename`? That returns a path that uses forward slash as the path separator. I recommend normalizing it via `os.path.normpath`. This is primarily for text output / printing, but also for cleaner exception messages and the occasional use case that requires backslash as the path separator.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, sorry I wasn't at my PC at the time so couldn't check it. Thank you for your answer and your time. Have a good day

Comment: Safer to use backslashes, quoting them as necessary in literal strings.  Windows support for forward slashes is patchy.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, `normpath` converts to backslash and resolves "." and ".." components. In Python 3.6+ I'd instead recommend using an instance of `pathlib.Path`, which has the special method `__fspath__`. Much of the standard library has been updated to call [`os.fspath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=__fspath__#os.fspath) (or [`PyOS_FsPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sys.html?highlight=pyos_fspath#c.PyOS_FSPath) in C) for path parameters, and it's an ongoing task to convert the rest of the standard library and popular packages on PyPI.